# Need mod_rewrite to only Redirect if a pattern is found in a RewriteMap

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to use mod_rewrite to check if a certain pattern is in a txt file and only redirect if it is found. I want to redirect url's to a splash page based on whether or not they contain a user ID that is found in the map file.

All of the user id's conform to the same pattern, so I match that pattern and feed it to my mapping. lets say a user id might look like this

```
12ab-34bc-5601
```

The matching of the pattern and subsequent redirection works fine. If a match is found the user is redirected to my splash page. However if no match is found in the map they are redirected to the original request. this creates a redirect loop even when I use the `L` flag.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap UserBlockMap txt:/home/username/users.map
RewriteRule <user id pattern> ${UserBlockMap:$3|$1} [R,L,NE]
```

Is there anything I can do to break this redirect loop or is RewriteMap just not the tool I want to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not realize before but the RewriteRule can go back up and Check a RewriteCond. the solution I found was this.

```
RewriteCond ${UserBlockMap:$3}  !^$  [NC]
RewriteRule <user id pattern> ${UserBlockMap:$3|$1} [R,L,NE]
```

based off of what is outlined in this blog post.
http://www.jeremytunnell.com/posts/mod_rewrite-attempting-to-bend-rewritemap-rewritecond-and-rewriterule-to-my-will

Comment: to make it more readable we usually write it like that: `RewriteCond ${UserBlockMap:$3|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND`